# JTextField not appearing on top of JFrame

Tags: java

How do I get a textbox to appear on this JFrame? Also is it good practice to build everything on top of the JFrame itself? Or is it better to overlay a JPanel and build everything on top of that?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class GUI {

    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

    public GUI() {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BufferedImage myImage = null;
        try {
            myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Desktop/background.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        frame.setContentPane(new ImageFrame(myImage));

        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(); 
        dimension.setSize(950, 800);
        frame.setSize(dimension);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: JFrames have an underlying container, so adding a JPanel isn't necessary. However if you want your frame to be easily added to a container somewhere else, then it's really easy if it's already all a JPanel. I did this for an application once for adding chat boxes to different screens, but the main application was just the chat box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have replaced the default content pane with you own content pane. I would guess your content pane does not use a layout manager so the text field is never displayed.

Try something like:

```
//frame.setContentPane(new ImageFrame(myImage));
ImageFrame content = new ImageFrame(myImage));
content.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
frame.setContentPane(content);
```

Now you text field should be added to the south of your image panel.

> Also is it good practice to build everything on top of the JFrame itself?  Or is it better to overlay a JPanel and build everything on top of that?

The content pane of a JFrame is a JPanel, so it doesn't really matter what you do since your will be using a panel either way. The key is to manage the layout manager of your content pane.